# Sweetalert2 : Unable to trigger the validation message

Tags: sweetalert2

I have created this sequence of popups with [Sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

The user select an year, wait for generation of the report, and at the end can download the report.

This is the code (simplified)

```
var startYear = 2017;
$("#test").click(function(){

    var _id = ....;

    var listYears = {};
    for (var i = parseInt(moment().format("YYYY")); i >= startYear; i--) listYears[" " + i] = i;

    swal({
        title: "Data export",
        html : "Select a year and press the <strong>export</strong> button.",
        reverseButtons : true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText : "Cancel",
        confirmButtonText: "Export",
        validationMessage : "Select a year",
        inputClass : "form-control", /* bootstrap 4 class */
        input: "select",
        inputOptions: listYears,
        inputPlaceholder: "Select..",
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

            swal({
                title: 'Wait',
                text: 'Report generation in progress..',
                allowOutsideClick : false,
                showConfirmButton : false,
                onOpen: () => {

                    swal.showLoading();

                    var dataGET = ".....&id=" + _id + "&year=" + parseInt(result.value);
                    var xhr = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: ".....php",
                        data : dataGET,
                        cache: false,
                        success : function(val){
                            var _this = this;
                            if(val == "OK_DOWNLOAD"){

                                var pathDownload = xhr.getResponseHeader(".....");
                                var nameDownload = xhr.getResponseHeader(".....");

                                swal({
                                    type : "success",
                                    title: 'Perfect',
                                    html : 'Now you can download the report<br/><a class="btn btn-custom-secondary mt-3" href="......" target="_blank" id="tempBtnDownloadReport"><span class="icon-download1"></span></a>',
                                    showConfirmButton : false,
                                }); 

                                $("#tempBtnDownloadReport").click(function(){
                                    swal.close();
                                });

                            }else{
                                _this.error();
                            }
                        },
                        error : function(){
                            swal("Attention","Error creating report, please try again.","error");
                        },
                        complete : function(jqXHR,textStatus){
                            swal.hideLoading();
                            xhr = null;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

My problem is when the user press the export button and the select it hasn't been "selected". I would like to trigger the error message ("Select a year"), something like [these examples](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-select).

Comment: If i understood correctly, you should add an `inputValidator` in the first `swal`. This input validator will not load the the 2nd swal unless the user selected a year. If that is what you want to achieve I can give you a full example of that.

Comment: Yes is this what i want. I tried with inputValidator, but i had problems.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

I used the **preConfirm** event.

```
 swal({
        title: "Data export",
        html : "Select a year and press the <strong>export</strong> button.",
        reverseButtons : true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText : "Cancel",
        confirmButtonText: "Export",
        validationMessage : "Select a year",
        inputClass : "form-control",
        input: "select",
        inputOptions: listYears,
        inputPlaceholder: "Select..",
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
        preConfirm: (test) => {
           if(test == "") Swal.showValidationMessage("Select a year");
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

            swal({
                title: 'Wait',
                text: 'Report generation in progress..',
                allowOutsideClick : false,
                showConfirmButton : false,
                onOpen: () => {

                    swal.showLoading();

                    var dataGET = "category=download&cmd=do_excel_report&id=" + _id + "&year=" + parseInt(result.value);

                    var xhr = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/" + $("html").data("project") + "/home/command.php",
                        data : dataGET,
                        cache: false,
                        success : function(val){
                            var _this = this;
                            if(val == "OK_DOWNLOAD"){

                                var pathDownload = xhr.getResponseHeader("Custom-Success-Download-Path");
                                var nameDownload = xhr.getResponseHeader("Custom-Success-Download-Name");

                                swal({
                                    type : "success",
                                    title: 'Perfect',
                                    html : 'Now you can download the report<br/><a class="btn btn-custom-secondary mt-3" href="/' + $("html").data("project") + "/home/command.php?category=download&cmd=download_excel_report&path=" + pathDownload + "&name=" + nameDownload + '" target="_blank" id="tempBtnDownloadReport"><span class="icon-download1"></span></a>',
                                    showConfirmButton : false,
                                }); 

                                $("#tempBtnDownloadReport").click(function(){
                                    swal.close();
                                });

                            }else{
                                _this.error();
                            }
                        },
                        error : function(){
                            swal("Attention","Error creating report, please try again.","error");
                        },
                        complete : function(jqXHR,textStatus){
                            swal.hideLoading();
                            xhr = null;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        }
    });
```